# How to free the memory taken by other apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory

I am writing an app, that needs to, basically, free the multitasking panel in iOS, so by pressing one button the memory frees and the apps disappear from the multitasking panel. Is there any not-banned by Apple way to do it without private APIs?

Thank you!

Comment: Even if you could kill other apps, that still wouldn't remove them from the multitasking panel. The panel is actually a list of recently used apps, not currently running ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, but the iOS terminate apps by himself when needs memory (whithout removing icons)

> In addition, if memory becomes
>   constrained, the system might remove
>   applications from memory to make more
>   room. If your application is currently
>   suspended, the system kills your
>   application and removes it from memory
>   without any notice.

source : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW47

Answer (score 6):

No, this isn't possible with the documented API's.  Your app is running in a sandbox and you don't have any access to (or knowledge of) the other apps that are running.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this, since each app is sandboxed and can only access itself and its own data. While this is likely the answer you don't want to hear, this is the reality.